# Trying to get openai's multi-agent-emergence-environments to work on Google Colab to learn

Tags: google-colaboratory, reinforcement-learning, openaiembeddings

I am new to RL, finished two courses and currently trying to learn the actual coding.
My PC is weak, so I am using Google Colab. While trying to imitate the work here:
https://github.com/openai/multi-agent-emergence-environments

When running hide_and_seek.py, I get the following error:

```
CompileError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/unixccompiler.py in _compile(self, obj, src, ext, cc_args, extra_postargs, pp_opts)
    185             self.spawn(compiler_so + cc_args + [src, '-o', obj] + extra_postargs)
    186         except DistutilsExecError as msg:
--> 187             raise CompileError(msg)
    188 
    189     def create_static_lib(

CompileError: command '/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1
```

Here is the file I am working on: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1LF6_HbFDlUAjDAEILTxXFWzlqFtuP2HQ?usp=sharing

Help is much appreciated!

I tried opening the environment, but I am unable to.